# Deselect text in sublime text vintage mode without escape key

Tags: vim, sublimetext2

In Sublime Text 2, I use the escape key to deselect text. In vintage mode, this also maps to command mode with the result that I am always unintentionally entering command mode.

How do I either:

1. Deselect text using a different key than escape

-OR-

1. Replace the escape key mapping to command mode with something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use other keys to exit insert mode by changing `C:\Users\lhuang\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Vintage\Default.sublime-keymap`. For example, I use double `;` to exit insert mode.

```
{ "keys": [";", ";"], "command": "exit_insert_mode",
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.command_mode", "operand": false },
        { "key": "setting.is_widget", "operand": false }
    ]
},

{ "keys": [";", ";"], "command": "exit_visual_mode",
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.command_mode"},
        { "key": "num_selections", "operand": 1},
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": false }
    ]
},
```

Comment: Awesome. I mapped mine to "super+escape". Thanks!